# Invoke remote program with socat and wait for it to complete

Tags: shell, socat

I need to invoke a program `x` on server *foo* from client *bar*. Program `x` takes some time to load, then reads input from stdin and transmits output to stdout before terminating. I've been trying to use `socat` to accomplish this.

On server *foo* I setup the following:

```
socat -lmlocal2 TCP-LISTEN:4444,fork,reuseaddr,linger=6 SYSTEM:x
```

And to invoke the command I run this on client *bar*:

```
echo "someinput" | socat - TCP:foo:4444
```

When I run the client with -v I can see `socat` is transmitting the data to *foo*, and if I run `top` on *foo* I can see it invoking `x` (which takes awhile to start up), but the client on *bar* doesn't wait around for `x` to finish, and `socat` on server *foo* reports an I/O error.

If I change the `SYSTEM` command on *foo* to `"SYSTEM:sleep 5; cat > /tmp/test ; echo 'done'"`, it does correctly read however much input I send it and puts it into `/tmp/test`. The input is all transmitted over the network and fed to `x`, it's just the output of `x` that is lost.

How do I get the `socat` client to stay open until `x` finishes writing to stdout and closes it? I tried adding `linger=6` to the server but that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I have it: put `-t 10` on both client **and** server, and they'll both wait 10 seconds after EOF from the client before closing both sockets.

Protip: use lots of `-d` to get a view into what socat is doing behind the scenes, and create a simple local test case you can easily reproduce.